# Reusing views with MVVM Light

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, view, mvvm-light

I have a solution divided in different projects.

I want to reuse views that are stored in a common project that the other projects are referencing.
So, let's assume i have a custom view which is a custom button :

```
    <Button BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource    CommonButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Content>
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Title" Style="{StaticResource CommonButtonTitleStyle}" Margin="0" />
                <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="SubTitle" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource CommonButtonSubTitleStyle}" />
            </Grid>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
```

Should i create a ViewModel per View (where i have to create properties and commands for the specific view), in order to fill a StackPanel with my Custom Button?

UPDATE:

i ended up with creating a UserControl containing my button where TextBlock's Text and Button Command are setted. 
Then i created an abstract View Model with properties and a RelayCommand required.

Created View Models that extends my abstract View Model to implement different actions for my RelayCommand for each button that i needed.

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: If your button will do the work every time, you can use the same viewmodel. For the content in your button, you can associate un model.
{Binding Model.Name}  {Binding Model.LastName}
So create an user controll with a viewmodel will be good.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make re-usable controls, the best solution is to create a new UserControl.

The example here should be sufficient to get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714088(v=vs.105).aspx

If you want to fill your StackPanel with your Button, you would simply import the CustomUserControl's namespace and add it to the XAML like any other control.